# Asynchronous preference toggle in Rails 4 throwing jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on forum for my organization's member built in rails.  We are trying to set up an asynchronous update of a db record for email preference.  When you click the link, it toggles to the next option.  It was working originally, but suddenly I'm getting this error and I'm puzzled by it.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**helper.rb**

```
 def email_preference_link(role, current_user)
    link_to email_preference(role.id, current_user.id).titleize, toggle_permissions_path(role_id: role.id), method: :put, remote: true, title: 'Click to rotate between Individual, Daily Digest or Opt-Out', id: "discussion_group_email_preference_#{role.discussion_group.id}"
 end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :permissions do
    collection do
      put :toggle
    end
  end
```

**Console error:**

[image: Chrome Console Error]

**HTML Render**:

```
<div class='col-md-3'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='red-text-email-preferences'>
       Email Preference:
       <a data-method="put" data-remote="true" href="/permissions/toggle?role_id=3" id="discussion_group_email_preference_1" rel="nofollow" title="Click to rotate between Individual, Daily Digest or Opt-Out">Individual</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.  I'm having trouble understanding the problem because the stack trace is not showing an error in the code I wrote, but in the way jQuery is trying to render it.

UPDATE 1:

**Rails Console**
[image: Rails Console Output]

**Problem Method**

```
def toggle
  @pref = permission.change_email_pref(@permission.email_preference)
end
```

So, I realize now that @permission is nil and that is the problem.  I'm now trying to figure out why it's nil.

Comment: Does the method work properly without the remote: true option?

Comment: Could you post the rails server logs, when you are getting 500 internal server error in browser?

Comment: Check `before_action :set_permission` or `before_filter :set_permission` of the controller, does it include `:toggle`?

Comment: In the permissions controller I have: before_action :set_role, only: [:toggle]